# Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, components

I've been trying to create a dynamic component loader example to proof out some ideas, however I've been completely unsuccessful in getting it to work.  I've followed the Angular documentation to a T and even explored solutions here on SO.  Nothing has given me any progress yet and I'm not sure where to go from here.

When running the code, I get the error `"Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined at ParentComponent.ngAfterViewInit"`

I'm using Angular 8 if that matters, but as far as I can tell this is sound, yet I can never get my component to display.  Thoughts?

Below is my code:

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('ref', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) ref: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
        this.ref.createComponent(factory);
    }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
    <div fxFlex="grow" fxLayout="column" ngClass="scroll">
        <ng-template ref></ng-template>
    </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<ng-template #ref>` (with the `#`)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, Oddly enough that worked to get the view to pop in, which is weird since in their documentation they don't have the # included in the HTML
https://stackblitz.com/angular/yargbdeqxom

Comment: @ConnorsFan, would you like to make an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var), make sure that the variable name is preceded by the hash symbol `#`. In the present case, the template syntax would be:

```
<ng-template #ref></ng-template>
```